# add class by set attribute

Tags: product, product-attribute, attribute-set

How to add a class on the product page that has a specific set attributes?

I know in xml

```
<reference name="root">
　　    <action method="addBodyClass">
　　        <className>account-page</className>
　　    </action>
</reference>
```

but i need for specific set attributes

Comment: do you want for specific attribute or for attribute set both are the different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom module and override `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View` Helper **OR** put it to local codepool at `\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Product\View.php`

Now Update `initProductLayout` method of `View.php` helper

```
public function initProductLayout($product, $controller)
{
    ...

    $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_TYPE_' . $product->getTypeId());
    $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_' . $product->getId());

    //adding handle for custom VIEW pages
    $update->addHandle('CUSTOMPRODUCTVIEW_' . $product->getAttributeSetId());
    //END adding handle for custom VIEW pages

    $controller->loadLayoutUpdates();

    ...
}
```

Now you can use/add handles like this (in `local.xml`)

```
...

<CUSTOMPRODUCTVIEW_21>
    <reference name="root">
　　    <action method="addBodyClass">
　　        <className>CLASS-FOR-21-attr</className>
　　    </action>
    </reference>
</CUSTOMPRODUCTVIEW_21>
<CUSTOMPRODUCTVIEW_23>
    <reference name="root">
　　    <action method="addBodyClass">
　　        <className>CLASS-FOR-23-attr</className>
　　    </action>
    </reference>
</CUSTOMPRODUCTVIEW_23>

...
```

**Where 21 and 23 are IDs of attribute sets, change them with your attribute set IDs**

Comment: Good one anil sir. very descriptive