# Can I dynamically change Layouts?

Tags: magento2, module, layout, magento-1, custom

On the view.phtml is it possible to write php to change the layout depending on what item is displayed on that page?

Using code similar to this:

```
$this->loadLayout()
                   ->getLayout()
                   ->getBlock('root')
                   ->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');      
$this->renderLayout();
```

Comment: If you have products assigned to specific attribute sets, then you can set layouts depending on attribute sets, check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114715/add-class-by-set-attribute/114721#114721

Answer (score 1):

No.

Templates belong to blocks, blocks belong to layouts and are loaded and generated by them. Therefore you can't change the layout from inside itself.

You can/should only change layout templates from a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at product level from admin.

1. Create a custom view.phtml in `template/catalog/product/my_view.phtml`
2. Navigate in the admin to `Product->Design->Custom Layout Update`

Add this block:

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/my_view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Zou can do That But Before that You have load a new layout handle by adding plugin to `Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout`

Please [check this Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/297780/78648) You will Get Help if You need clarification i will do it for you please let me know